# Calculate percent change between multiple columns of a data frame

Tags: r, function, dplyr, difference

I have a data frame as follows :

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
week1 <- c(234,567456, 134123, 13412421, 2345245)
week2 <- c(4234,5123456, 454123, 12342421, 8394545)
week3 <- c(1234, 234124, 12348, 9348522, 134534)
data <- data.frame(id, week1, week2, week3)
```

I would like to find the percent change between week1 and week2, and then week2 and week3 etc (my dataframe is much larger with about 27 columns).

I tried:

```
data$change1 <- (data$week2-data$week1)*100/data$week1
```

However this would be extensive with a larger dataset.

Comment: Mathematical operator have methods for `data.frame`s in R; `(data[-(1:2)] - data[-c(1, ncol(data))]) * 100 / data[-c(1, ncol(data))]`

Comment: When I try this on my larger dataset I receive an error stating ```Error in Ops.data.frame(table_names[-(1:7)], table_names[-c(1, 27)]) : 
  ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames``` Any suggestions as to why this is occurring? My df is 12714 rows by 27 cols

Comment: I am trying to find the percent change from columns 7 to 27 (end)

Comment: In you first subset (`table_names[-(1:7)]`), you remove all non-data columns (`1:6`) and the first data column (`7`). In the second subset (`table_names[-c(1, 27)]`), you only remove the first and the last column. Thus, the two subset have different number of columns, hence the (informative) message: "`-` only defined for equally-sized data frames". You need to adjust the second subset so that you remove the last column and _all_ non-data columns. I leave that to you. Cheers

Comment: @JaneMiller if the answer below helps, please accept the answer so that it is not shown as unanswered any longer, and if you think it is helpful, you can even upvote it. If it did not answer your query, feel free to explain the remaining issue. You may want to do the same for any other question you have asked that has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- gather(df, key='week', value='value', -id)

df$week <- as.integer(as.character((gsub('week', '', df$week))))
df %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(week) %>% mutate(perc_change = (value-lag(value,1))/lag(value,1)*100)
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   id [5]
      id  week    value perc_change
   <dbl> <int>    <dbl>       <dbl>
 1     1     1      234       NA   
 2     2     1   567456       NA   
 3     3     1   134123       NA   
 4     4     1 13412421       NA   
 5     5     1  2345245       NA   
 6     1     2     4234     1709.  
 7     2     2  5123456      803.  
 8     3     2   454123      239.  
 9     4     2 12342421       -7.98
10     5     2  8394545      258.  
11     1     3     1234      -70.9 
12     2     3   234124      -95.4 
13     3     3    12348      -97.3 
14     4     3  9348522      -24.3 
15     5     3   134534      -98.4
```

This works reasonably well, but assumes that there is an observation every week, or else your percent change will be based on the last available week (so, if week 3 is missing, the value for week 4 will be a week on week change with week 2 as basis).

(Edit: replaced `substr` with `gsub`)

Sense checking:

For row 6, you see id 1. This is week 2 with a value of 4234. In week 1, id 1 had a value of 234. The difference is

```
(4234-234)/234
[1] 17.09402
```

So, that is aligned.